# Strict equality and loose equality with logical and operator

Tags: javascript, equality

Is it considered a bad practice to combine a loose equality check (foo != null) with a strict equality check (bar === true)?

In my opinion, they should both be compared with the strict equality, or both be compared with the loose equality check.

Is there ever a scenario where I would need to have a loose equality check combined with a strict equality check?

Thanks Stackoverflow!

Looking forward to your insight!

```
const foobar = foo != null && bar === true;
```

Edit, this question differs from [Which equals operator (== vs ===) should be used in JavaScript comparisons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons) because, this is particularly on combining a loosely equal comparison with a strict equal comparison. This stack overflow question referenced above is only in conjunction with using one or the other.

I am particularly interested if its ever a valid use case to use both a loose equal, with a strict equal inside a comparison.

Comment: It's not the *combination* of them that's the issue, it's the use of loose equality *at all* IMO

Comment: i agree with @CertainPerformance. if your code requires the use of loose equality there is a fundamental problem in your design.

Comment: Loose equality is very useful for comparing to `null` because it includes `undefined` and nothing else. Doing `foo != null` is so much nicer than `foo !== null && foo !== undefined`.

Comment: @ziggywiggy ahh I see. That makes total sense! Thank you.

Comment: Yep, you're welcome.